# Center tap transformer- How do we get voltages that are 180 out of phase?

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity

I have been reading that in a center tap transformer, we get 2 voltages which are 180 out of phase. Can someone please explain how that happens.?

Comment: See my revised diagram better showing how the center tapped voltages are 180 out of phase.

Answer (score 1):

Think of two bights (cycles, loops) of a helical piece of wire with the same magnetic flux threading both of them. See diagram below (please don't shoot at the artist, she is doing her best):

[image]

Now apply Faraday's law to both loops: for any flux change with time, the EMF of point B relative to A is the same as that of C relative to B. Thus, if we add a tap at point B, then $V_{CB} = V_{BA}$, which also means that $V_{CB}=-V_{AB}$, so, if these voltages vary sinusoidally with time, the are $180^\circ$ out of phase.

if there's an ferrous or otherwise high permeability core, this makes the idealization almost perfect, for then almost all the flux is confined to the core, so all flux that goes through one loop goes through the other.

Answer (score 0):

A 120/240 center-tapped secondary winding of a transformer is the typical means of supplying household power in the US. The center-tap is connected to earth ground. The secondary sinusoidal voltage is 240 vac between the outer legs, +120 Vac between one leg and ground and -120 Vac between the other leg and ground, making the two 120 Vac circuits $180^\circ$ out of phase. See circuit diagram below. Applying Kirchhoff's voltage law: clockwise +120 +120 -240 = 0.

The 120 Vac circuits generally supply lighting and general branch circuit outlets while the 240 Vac circuits supply major appliance loads (electric ranges, ACs, clothes dryers, etc.). Neutral conductors of the 120 vac branch circuits are connected to ground. The center-tapped ground assures the maximum voltage to ground for the 240 Vac circuits in the household is less than 150 Vac (reducing risk of severe electric shock to ground).

[image]

Comment: If effective voltage is 120 V, then the maximum voltage is $120\sqrt{2}=170$ V.

Comment: @JánLalinský Correct. Got a little sloppy there. will correct. Thanks.

Comment: Do you think 120 V causes meaningfully less harmful shock than 240 V? Numerically, yes, but in practical terms, I would think both are lethal if supplied by a hard supplier such as the power grid.

Comment: @JánLalinský The higher the voltage to ground, the greater the risk (potential severity) of electric shock event, all other things being equal. NFPA 70 (National Electrical Code) requires most equipment involving voltage to ground greater than 150 v to be either grounded or double insulated.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to understand your statement "The center-tapped ground ... reducing risk of severe electric shock to ground". It obviously reduces  mathematical risk and allows manufacturer to build and sell cheaper equipment, but do electricians in US actually believe using 120 V as opposed to 240 V makes a meaningful difference in term of user safety?

Comment: @JánLalinský I can't tell you what electricians may or may not think, but the safety community (writers of safety standards and codes) have stricter electric shock protection requirements when the voltage to ground exceeds 150. In European households you have nominal 220 v to ground for all appliances. The safety standards there require most equipment to be either double insulated (IEC Class I) or double insulated (IEC Class II). If you don't like it you are always free to comment to the applicable NEC code panel or to the groups that develop and publish safety standards.